# Trying to randomise a jQuery content slider

Tags: javascript

I'm using a very nice jQuery content slider called Easy Slider on my site that I downloaded from Css Globe.

The script is excellent and does just what I want - except I can't make it randomise the list, it always scrolls from left to right or right to left!

I'm far from good with JavaScript, so my attempts at solving this have been feeble. Although I'm sure it must be an easy fix!

**If anyone wouldn't mind taking a glance over the script to see if they can spot what I need to change to make it random it would be greatly appreciated!**

I've tried contacting the original plugin developer but have had no response yet. The comments on the Easy Slider page didn't bear much fruit either unfortunately.

I've pasted the script I'm using on my site below:

```
/*
 *  Easy Slider 1.7 - jQuery plugin
 * written by Alen Grakalic 
 * http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
 * and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
 *
 * Built for jQuery library
 * http://jquery.com
 *
 */

(function($) {

 $.fn.easySlider = function(options){

  // default configuration properties
  var defaults = {   
   prevId:   'prevBtn',
   prevText:   'Previous',
   nextId:   'nextBtn', 
   nextText:   'Next',
   controlsShow: true,
   controlsBefore: '',
   controlsAfter: '', 
   controlsFade: true,
   firstId:   'firstBtn',
   firstText:   'First',
   firstShow:  false,
   lastId:   'lastBtn', 
   lastText:   'Last',
   lastShow:  false,    
   vertical:  false,
   speed:    800,
   auto:   false,
   pause:   7000,
   continuous:  false, 
   numeric:   false,
   numericId:   'controls'
  }; 

  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

  this.each(function() {  
   var obj = $(this);     
   var s = $("li", obj).length;
   var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
   var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
   var clickable = true;
   obj.width(w); 
   obj.height(h); 
   obj.css("overflow","hidden");
   var ts = s-1;
   var t = 0;
   $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);   

   if(options.continuous){
    $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
    $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
    $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
   };    

   if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

   if(options.controlsShow){
    var html = options.controlsBefore;    
    if(options.numeric){
     html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
    } else {
     if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
     html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
     html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
     if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';    
    };

    html += options.controlsAfter;      
    $(obj).after(html);          
   };

   if(options.numeric){         
    for(var i=0;i<s;i++){      
     $(document.createElement("li"))
      .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
      .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
      .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
      .click(function(){       
       animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
      });             
    };       
   } else {
    $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){  
     animate("next",true);
    });
    $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){  
     animate("prev",true);    
    }); 
    $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){  
     animate("first",true);
    });    
    $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){  
     animate("last",true);    
    });    
   };

   function setCurrent(i){
    i = parseInt(i)+1;
    $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
    $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
   };

   function adjust(){
    if(t>ts) t=0;  
    if(t<0) t=ts; 
    if(!options.vertical) {
     $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
    } else {
     $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
    }
    clickable = true;
    if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
   };

   function animate(dir,clicked){
    if (clickable){
     clickable = false;
     var ot = t;    
     switch(dir){
      case "next":
       t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? t+1 : ts) : t+1;      
       break; 
      case "prev":
       t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? t-1 : 0) : t-1;
       break; 
      case "first":
       t = 0;
       break; 
      case "last":
       t = ts;
       break; 
      default:
       t = dir;
       break; 
     }; 
     var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
     var speed = diff*options.speed;      
     if(!options.vertical) {
      p = (t*w*-1);
      $("ul",obj).animate(
       { marginLeft: p }, 
       { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
      );    
     } else {
      p = (t*h*-1);
      $("ul",obj).animate(
       { marginTop: p }, 
       { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
      );     
     };

     if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){     
      if(t==ts){
       $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
       $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
      } else {
       $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
       $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();     
      };
      if(t==0){
       $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
       $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
      } else {
       $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
       $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
      };     
     };    

     if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
     if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       animate("next",false);
      },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
     };

    };

   };
   // init
   var timeout;
   if(options.auto){;
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     animate("next",false);
    },options.pause);
   };  

   if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);

   if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){     
    $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
    $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();    
   };    

  });

 };

})(jQuery);
```

Many thanks again!

Alec

Comment: what about it do you want randomised? I don't quite understand.

Comment: This is a slider which appears in the header on every page of my site http://www.hondacivicforum.co.uk/ All I really need is for the user not to see the slider starting from the same place on every page load. I'd like to give equal prominence to each promo in the slider.

I guess I don't mind how technically random it is, whichever is simplest. It would be nice though if we had some prevention for it displaying the same <li> twice in a row.

Comment: what is the code that generates your list? It would be simpler to randomise the list than to hack Easy Slider.

Comment: The list is just hard coded into the global header for the site. It's a simple unordered list which you can see in the header of my site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [shuffle plugin](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/) to randomize the list.

Or, you could pick a random starting element to set to current with an expression like `initialIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * numberOfItems)`